# Error on cancelling order (PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided))

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-standard

I needed to cancel an order on my site but. when I clicked cancel I get this error message

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided)**

The **PayPal payment has been cancelled but the Order status will not update to cancelled.**

Whats going here?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the order transaction has already been voided on PayPal and Magento is trying to void it again whenever you try to cancel it. If you check this transaction on your PayPal account you will see it is voided.

What you can do is to update the payment module code to bypass the error #10600 and cancel the order anyway.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the Paypal payment wasn't voided before I pressed Cancel, though the Paypal payment was voided when I pressed cancel which is what is confusing me. The Payment was voided but the order wasn't cancelled and I got the error message.